# How to create a postrgesql function for dynamic query and executing dml statements

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to create a function which could do cases below?

- input1:"myquery"='select * from table1' -->  returns query results (dynamic columns depends on query)
- input2:"myquery"='insert into table 2 values (1)' --> executes dml statement

Dummy sample:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."myquery_func"("myquery" text)   
 --  RETURNS TABLE(???)   
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$  
DECLARE 
   "@mysql" character varying;  
BEGIN   
  execute "myquery";  
END; 
$function$;
```

Comment: Why, oh why, do people want to do all kind of weird things with functions?

Comment: I think that this function have no sense and is unuseful.

Comment: You are right but that is for migration from different db so looking for a way to do it postgresql